# Want to convert go gRPC client and server into WASM and run it successfully

Tags: go, grpc, webassembly, wasmtime

I've a basic go grpc client and server running fine and I want to change the client and server into WASM and want to run the wasm file to communicate between server and client through that WASM file that use the gRPC protocol.

Below is the github link of the basic go gRPC client server code.
[go-grpc-wasm](https://github.com/siashish/go-grpc-wasm.git)

Any one have any idea about that will be much helpful and appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

I try convert server and client separately into WASM and run it using Wasmedge and got the below error.

```
wasmedge server.wasm 

[2023-09-21 16:11:21.373] [error] instantiation failed: unknown import, Code: 0x62
[2023-09-21 16:11:21.373] [error]     When linking module: "go" , function name: "debug"
[2023-09-21 16:11:21.373] [error]     At AST node: import description
[2023-09-21 16:11:21.373] [error]     At AST node: import section
[2023-09-21 16:11:21.374] [error]     At AST node: modulee
```

Comment: I think this isn't possible (yet). I found the documentation to be lacking but the WASM targets (`GOOS=wasip1 GOARCH=wasm`) are not yet functionally equivalently to e.g. `GOOS=linux`. Not all syscalls are implemented in particular networking. So WASM isn't a generic target for Go code. You will also need to choose a WASM runtime that supports the functionally you need

Comment: I find Go team's [Go Build Dashboard](https://build.golang.org/) useful. If you scroll to the right hand side (the horizontal scrollbar can be tricky to grab), you'll find the results for `wasip1` and you'll see that wasmtime and wazero are good runtime choices.

Comment: Thanks for you guys response.
When I try this command `GOOS=wasip1 GOARCH=wasm go build -o server.wasm server.go` got the below error `go: unsupported GOOS/GOARCH pair wasip1/wasm`